# Get Client Ip Kentico 9

Tags: ip, kentico, ip-geolocation

I need to get the country of the customer who comes to the site.
I can use `GeoIPHelper.GetCountryByIp("ip")`to get Counry, but how can I get the ip address of the client that comes to the site?

Comment: Are you using a load balancer in your network environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Kentico EMS? If so then to get country of current contact:

```
var countryId = ContactManagementContext.CurrentContact.ContactCountryId;
var country = CoutryInfoProvider.GetCountryInfo(countryId);
```

Or

```
var currentLocation = GeoIPHelper.GetCurrentGeoLocation();
```

Which also contains country/state based on current request.

Answer (score 0):

`{%Ip%}` in macro or `var clientIp = CMS.Helpers.RequestContext.UserHostAddress`

Or do you want to find out ip of existing customers?

That would be a sql query like

```
select Convert(xml,UserLastLogonInfo)  
from COM_Customer Join CMS_User on CustomerUserID = UserID
```

it will give your xml like:

```
<info>
  <agent></agent>
  <ip></ip>
</info>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code sample, I *think* you're in the code behind somewhere.  This is possibly more of a general thing with ASP.NET.  if that is the case, you can use `HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress` to get the IP of the current user.

There can be issues with this however if you're behind something like a load balancer.  To combat that, you can try something like the following:

```
string userAddress = string.Empty;

if (HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] != null)
{
    userAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"].ToString();
}
else if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress.Length != 0)
{
    userAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
}

var country = GeoIPHelper.GetCountryByIp(userAddress);
```

`CMS.Helpers.RequestContext` also works (as Shof says) but again, make sure to cater for any load balancer issues.  To be honest, I've always fallen back to just using the HttpContext method from pre-Kentico habit.

Answer (score 0):

```
GeoLocation currentGeoLocation = GeoIPHelper.GetCurrentGeoLocation();
if (currentGeoLocation != null)
{
    var countryAndState = ValidationHelper.GetString(currentGeoLocation.CountryName, "");
    var ipCountryCode = ValidationHelper.GetString(currentGeoLocation.CountryCode, "");
    var ipRegion = ValidationHelper.GetString(currentGeoLocation.RegionName, "");
    var ipCity = ValidationHelper.GetString(currentGeoLocation.City, "");
}
```

or macro

```
{% AnalyticsContext.CurrentGeoLocation.Country.CountryName%}
{% AnalyticsContext.CurrentGeoLocation.State%}
{% AnalyticsContext.CurrentGeoLocation.City%}
{% AnalyticsContext.CurrentGeoLocation.Postalcode%}
```